# Pass json data by selecting id using fresh scope in angularjs

Tags: json, angularjs

I have a table in a template which is retrieving json data something like this 
`

```
id   type   date
755  video  21/09/12
```

`.

here is my controller of retrieving data for table

```
   .controller('list', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get(baseUrl + '/page/1', _auth)
    .success(function(data) {
      $scope.value = data.data;
    }, function(err) {
        console.error(err);
    });
    $scope.detail = function(index) {
      $http.get(baseUrl + '/page')
    }
  })
```

for routing i am using ui-router and doing something like this

```
$stateProvider
   .state('/get' , {
     url: '/data',
     templateUrl: 'app/list/data/data.html'
   })
```

This page also has button which redirects you to a different template on clicking any row from table. All I want is by clicking any row it redirects you to a different template and will show data only related to the id clicked. How can i achieve this? Any Help ?

Thankx

Comment: you should first try something by your own, when you stuck ask question.  Ask questions not whole solutions? plz

Comment: This can be done several ways.  Are you using a route or just a another template on the same route.  Also, seeing your code would help.

Comment: Give a look at ui-sref to switch state on a click.

Comment: i am using ui-sref @Okazari

Comment: i have no problem in routing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need a route to display this particular element :

```
$stateProvider
   .state('/get' , {
     url: '/data',
     templateUrl: 'app/list/data/data.html'
   })
   .state('/getone' , {
     url: '/data/:id',
     templateUrl: 'app/list/data/detail.html',
     controller:"MyController"
   })
```

You will have a param ":id" that will give you the element to show.

You can get it in your controller like this :

```
app.controller('MyController', function($scope, $stateParams) {
    $scope.myDataId = $stateParams.id
});
```

You can navigate to this using this ui-sref syntax :

```
ui-sref="/getone({id:myelementid})"
```

Currently working on an exemple in plunker.

Hope it helped.

EDIT : Here is a clean "How to do"

See it in this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/xKsipSblmAoN9F1yU9se?p=preview)

**My states definition**

```
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/datalist');
  $stateProvider
  .state('datalist', {
    url: '/datalist',
    templateUrl: 'data.html',
    controller: 'DataCtrl',
  })
  .state('datadetail', {
    url: '/datadetail/:id',
    templateUrl: 'detail.html',
    controller: 'DetailCtrl',
  })
});
```

My controllers :

```
app.controller('DataCtrl', function($scope, $http){
  $http.get("all.json").success(function(datas){
    $scope.datas = datas;
  })
});

app.controller('DetailCtrl', function($scope, $http, $stateParams){
  $http.get($stateParams.id+".json").success(function(data){
    $scope.data = data;
  })
});
```

And finally the data template :

```
<div>Welcome to my awesome data list</div><br/>
<div ng-repeat="data in datas">
  <div>
    Data Id : {{data.id}}
  </div>  
  <div>
    Data name : {{data.name}}
  </div>
  <button ui-sref="datadetail({id:data.id})">See details of {{data.name}}</button>
</div>
```

I prefer a lot to not use a "/" in the state name till the state name is a technical name and will no be displayed.

If you have some trouble try to recreate your states, steps by steps.

**EDIT 2 : How to match the question behavior**

See it on this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/3hob2NurPXd1z2bD9buV?p=preview)

Here is how it would work with your "select" a row on a click.

Since you can refer to your "current" object of a "ng-repeat= data in datas" as "data". You are able to pass it to a function like this :

```
ng-repeat="data in datas" ng-click="select(data)"
```

The function simply affect this object to a var that represent the currently selected object :

```
$scope.select = function(data){
  $scope.selectedData = data;
};
```

Now you button will take the information about "selectedData"

```
<button ui-sref="datadetail({id:selectedData.id})" ng-disabled="!selectedData">
    See details of {{selectedData.name}}
</button>
```

And ... that's pretty much all. If you have the two states defined on my first exemple you will exactly have what you want.

Comment: its doing nothing :-(

Comment: @TanviSingh Updated with a clean custom exemple in plunker

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/JVvfxeIH8A6FuH5X74Rx  I want it like this. Button is disabled by default and when i click on any table row button will get enabled and redirect you to the page containing data related to the row clicked.

Comment: @TanviSingh Okey got it ! Let me do that.

Comment: @TanviSingh Edited the answer with a plunker and an explanation for your attended behavior.